# windows 10 cmd, what determines which files can be accessed without a path?

Tags: windows, powershell

in command line examples in windows 10 files seem to just be pulled from thin air? how do i define that?
commands like

```
gcc --v
```

or

```
link /subsystem:console /nodefaultlib /entry:main hello.obj
```

refer to downloaded files, but if i try to download them and run the identical command i will get an error:

> gcc : The term 'gcc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling   of
> the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
> and try again. At line:1 char:1

why? am i missing something?

Comment: Windows uses the PATH environment variable to find an executable specified on the command line without a path. So you need to add the location where gcc is installed to your PATH.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WIndows 10. The `PATH` environmental variable has been around since the days of MS-DOS 2.0 or so, as well as other OSes such as *nix and Mac OS. Directories listed in the `PATH` are used to search for executable commands when no path for an executable is included. On Windows 10, use the search box on the left side of the task bar to search for `Environtal variables`, and select `Edit environmental variables for your account` from the search results.

Comment: For command-line, after Windows searches %PATH%, it'll look in the current directory, but for PowerShell (which your error tells me you're using), you have to put ./ in front of the command to find it in the current directory.  So "gcc" becomes "./gcc.exe" (I think ./gcc works, too, but I tend to be explicit in PowerShell).

Answer (score 0):

Everything in `$ENV:Path` can be called without specifying a path.
If not, you must specify the path (even the current directory).